# Import Error when trying to migrate Google App Engine Python 2 app using NDB to the Cloud NDB Python 3 library

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, migration, app-engine-ndb

I am currently starting the [process](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/#overview) of preparing an App Engine app for Python 3 migration. 
During the first step:

> 1. Migrate the App Engine bundled services in your Python 2 app to Google Cloud services ...

Following all the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-cloud-ndb#updating) to switch the datastore module from `google.appengine.ext.ndb` to `google.cloud.ndb`, I immediately get the following Import Error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/---.py", line 8, in <module>
from google.cloud import ndb
  File "/home/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from google.cloud.ndb.client import Client
  File "/home/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/client.py", line 23, in <module>
from google.cloud import _helpers
  File "/home/test_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 29, in <module>
from six.moves import http_client

ImportError: No module named moves
```

This happens whether or not I am testing in a virtual environment. Importing `six.moves` works in a python console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with the bundled test server `dev_appserver.py`. Found it solved [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/issues/249#issuecomment-560957294) by Andrewsg:

> I think we've identified an issue with devappserver related to the six library specifically. Could you please try a workaround? Add the line: `import six; reload(six)` to the top of your app, before NDB is loaded

Comment: If the question is solved could you please accept the answer to give visibility to the solution?

Comment: Done. It said I had to wait 2 days to accept my own answer